# Python Click - name synonyms or abbreviations

Tags: python, python-click

I am using python click to implement a cli. Simplest example would allow me to say:

`./mytest.py help`

but also

`./mytest.py h`

In other words, the `help` command can be shortened to just `h`. This is the way many cli programs work, e.g. `git`.

From what I can tell the code snippet:

```
@click.command()
def help():
    click.echo("Help!)
```

Will allow me to have:

`./mytest.py help`

But I don't know how to allow the synonym. I can't find anything that explains this.

Answer (score 2):

In the Click documentation, this is known as "aliases".

The documentation at https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.x/advanced/ provides a code snippet for what you're looking for. Additionally, it links to sample code at
https://github.com/pallets/click/tree/master/examples/aliases.

Here is a minimal implementation for the example given:

```
import click


class AliasedGroup(click.Group):
    def get_command(self, ctx, cmd_name):
        if cmd_name in ["help", "h"]:
            return click.Group.get_command(self, ctx, "help")
        return None


@click.command(cls=AliasedGroup)
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command()
def help():
    click.echo("Help!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

Comment: To deal with multiple commands, one can replace `return None` by `return click.Group.get_command(self, ctx, cmd_name)`.

Answer (score 0):

I use the context forward method.

```
$ cat cli.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
  """
  cli commands 
  """

@cli.command()
def help():
  """
  Get help
  """
  click.echo("Help!")

@cli.command("h")
@click.pass_context
def another_help(ctx):
  """
  Another way of asking for help
  """
  ctx.forward(help)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

And here's a test run:

```
$ ./cli.py
Usage: cli.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  cli commands

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  h     Another way of asking for help
  help  Get help

$ ./cli.py h
Help!
$ ./cli.py help
Help!
```

For whatever reason, I also demonstrated that the command name and function name can be different:  I named the synonym function `another_help` but I told click the command is `h`.

The real issue with my approach is that the help text associated with the synonym must be copied, too.  More importantly, the parameters (that is, options and arguments) also have to be copied.

In essence, the `ctx.forward()` approach increases the maintenance burden.  It is easy to get them out of sync (let's say as you added additional options or arguments).

As you can see in the test run, the same command also gets listed twice.  And so, I often just hide the synonym so that the list of commands is clearer.  Plus, I don't have to keep the help text (Another way of asking for help) in sync.

So, here's an improved version, with the `h` synonym hidden:

```
$ cat cli.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
  """
  cli commands 
  """

@cli.command()
def help():
  """
  Get help
  """
  click.echo("Help!")

@cli.command("h",hidden=True)
@click.pass_context
def another_help(ctx):
  """
  Another way of asking for help
  """
  ctx.forward(help)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()


$ ./cli.py 
Usage: cli.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  cli commands

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  help  Get help
$ ./cli.py h
Help!
```

Finally, here's the "parameter problem":  if you add a parameter to one function, you have to add the same parameter to the synonym.

In the example below, I added a `--name` option to the `help` command, but not the `h` synonym:

```
$ cat cli.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
  """
  cli commands 
  """

@cli.command()
def help():
  """
  Get help
  """
  click.echo("Help!")

@cli.command("h",hidden=True)
@click.pass_context
def another_help(ctx):
  """
  Another way of asking for help
  """
  ctx.forward(help)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
$ vi cli.py
$ ./cli.py 
Usage: cli.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  cli commands

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  help  Get help
$ ./cli.py help Fred
Help, Fred!
$ ./cli.py h Fred
Usage: cli.py h [OPTIONS]
Try 'cli.py h --help' for help.

Error: Got unexpected extra argument (Fred)
```

Above, you can see that the `h` command has a problem with the argument.  And so, to correct this, I would also have to add name to the `another_help` function like this:

```
@cli.command("h",hidden=True)
@click.pass_context
@click.argument("name",required=False)
def another_help(ctx,name):
  """
  Another way of asking for help
  """
  ctx.forward(help)
```

And that's what I mean about the maintenance burden - adding parameters or options has to be done to both synonyms.